# React Native & Redux: Why aren't child components re-rendering on every state update?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, redux

In React Native and Redux, I have a `<NavigationCardStack/>` as a root component. And every time state has been updated, the redux-logger updates correctly with the next/new state.

And after the state change, when newly updated state is console logged in a child component, it doesn't console log the updated state but rather console logs the initial state (in the child component `childPage.js` and logging: `render(){ console.log(this.props.state) return(...) ...`).

Could it be that I am hooked up to Redux incorrectly or missing something? Because, everything seem to work perfectly fine and makes sense.

Thank you in advance!

**Here are some snippets of my code:**

This is my reducer and the child component would just log the initialState here even though other properties have been added and updated:

```
const initialState = {
  meetUp: false,
}

function itemReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {


    case ITEM_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        quantity: action.quantity
      }

    case ITEM_PRICE:
      return {
        ...state,
        price: action.price
      }

    case ITEM_MEET_UP:
      return {
        ...state,
        meetUp: action.meetUp
      }

     default:
       return state
  }
}

export default itemReducer
```

And connected to the root component like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    itemInfo: state.itemReducer,
    ...
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    itemQuantity: (value) => itemQuantity(value),
    itemPrice: (value) => itemPrice(value),
    itemMeetUp: (value) => itemMeetUp(value),
  }
)(NavigationRoot)
```

With following actions:

```
export function itemMeetUp(value) {
  return {
    type: ITEM_MEET_UP,
    meetUp: value
  }
}

export function itemQuantity(value) {
  return {
    type: ITEM_QUANTITY,
    quantity: value
  }
}

export function itemPrice(value) {
  return {
    type: ITEM_PRICE,
    price: value
  }
}
```

state={this.props} represent the state and how it is supposed to be passed down to child components

```
  _renderScene (props) {
    const { route } = props.scene

    return (
      <route.component _handleNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)} state={this.props}/>
    )
  }

    <NavigationCardStack
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      ...
    />
```

Comment: Its hard to tell from the snippets provided - any chance of putting up a github repo or jsfiddle?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you try to console.log from the componentWillReceiveProps(props) lifecycle method in your childPage.js component? Is that method ever getting called? If so, can you log the props argument to determine if the component is ever receiving the correct properties?

Comment: @bryonbean I did console log as `constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props)` and it does print out all the initial properties the very first time the page gets rendered. But then after being updated, the console log never gets called again, so it is never being re-rendered again despite the update on the state, correct?

Comment: No, the constructor will only get called once upon instantiation and this is where the initial/original properties get set. Subsequent re-rendering of the component's properties can be determined by adding a lifecycle method called `componentWillReceiveProps(props)`. Inside this method you can call `console.log(props)` to determine what new properties are being set on the component. (see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Comment: @bryonbean I tried it inside `render() { console.log(props) return()}`, and when the state gets updated, the console logs again but rather than the updated state, it console logs the initial state. And I tried   `componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log(props)
  }` before `render(){return()}` but never gets called and does not console log

Answer (score 2):

Could [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8084) be related? It seems similar in that `NavigationCardStack` won't update even though the redux state changes, and `redux-logger` logs the change. I can't tell from your code sample, but one way to test this might be to `connect` the children or one child directly to your redux store instead of having `NavigationCardStack` pass the store state in as props? That github issue above also has some hacky workarounds, but I'm not very familiar with react-native so I can't be much help there.

Comment: `connect` all the children directly to the redux is not suggested though, like it's not good practice?

Comment: It's not really considered bad practice. If you're concerned with performance that much you should definitely instrument and see for yourself, but the fashionable thing I've seen to do of late is to connect as low down the component tree as possible and only map the props you need. At the very least it makes moving components around in the hierarchy much less tedious.

Comment: but doesn't that defeat the purpose of redux? Where you would just want to keep it in one flow?

Comment: It doesn't defeat the purpose of redux. The main purpose is that all of your state comes from one central location. It's not bad practice to have many components access the single store, the hairiness occurs if you had multiple disparate stores and accessed them inconsistently. This is better summarized in the [principles section of the very excellent redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html). [This other section](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) is also relevant to this conversation and can be very enlightening. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a stab in the dark and based entirely on our conversation in the comments, but is the _renderScene method bound to the component in the constructor? E.g:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  ...
  this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: No worries, but yes I do have the method bound to the component in the constructor.

Comment: @JoKo without seeing more of how your code is constructed I'm at a loss, but I can tell you confidently that as far as your child component is concerned the value of `this.props` never changes; if it did the `componentWillReceiveProps` method would fire and you would be able to log them there. This means that your parent component also does not see a change. Wish I could be more help.

Comment: I too am at a loss. I can always provide more code. Which portion would you might need?

Comment: Checking in to see if you've seen my last example. Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this sooner. I'm guessing that the code snippet with `<NavigationCardStack ... />` is the root component? It would be nice to see that in its entirety as well as your all of the Redux code. One more thing, this style/code looks familiar, is it based on a tutorial from somewhere?